# Angular Custom Pipe not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have created a custom pipe for my project and included my pipe file in my module in the declartions array.

**search-user.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import {
  User
} from './user';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchUser'
})
export class SearchUserPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor() {
    console.log('imported');

  }

  transform(items: User[], filter: User): User[] {

    console.log('inside transform');
    if (!items || !filter) {
      return items;
    }
    return items.filter((item: User) => this.applyFilter(item, filter));
  }

  applyFilter(user: User, filter: User): boolean {
    for (const field in filter) {
      if (filter[field]) {
        if (typeof filter[field] === 'string') {
          if (user[field].toLowerCase().indexOf(filter[field].toLowerCase()) === -1) {
            return false;
          }
        } else if (typeof filter[field] === 'number') {
          if (user[field] !== filter[field]) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

**My user model which i have used in pipe.ts**

```
export class User {
    studentId: Number;
    name: String;
    email: String;
    phoneNumber: String;
}
```

**This is my html file in which i need to sort the data using the pipe**

```
<div *ngIf="dataLoaded" class="table-responsive">
  <table #myTable class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="filter.studentId" placeholder="ID"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="filter.name" placeholder="NAME"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="filter.email" placeholder="EMAIL"></th>
        <th><input type="text" name="title" [(ngModel)]="filter.phoneNumber" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id={{i}} *ngFor="let user of userDetails;let i of index | searchUser: filter">
        <td>{{user.studentId}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        <td>{{user.phoneNumber}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

I am trying to create filter for the every column of the table.
I have also checked if my pipe file is imported in my bundle by logging something into the constructor of the file.

I am stuck here the pipe is not working for any of the fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using wrong syntax ngFor in your html. Try this

```
*ngFor="let user of userDetails | searchUser: filter; index as i;">
```